# Sign in / log in page bootstrap php

Tags: php

This piece of code is still not working. The submit button isnt doing anything when i click it. Can someone tell me where i have gone wrong. As i just changed some html/css code to bootstrap and didnt change any variables or php code.

```
<?php
// Assign varibles
$submit = @$_POST['submit'];

//variables to prevent errors
$account = "";
$gender = "";
$name = "";
$email = "";
$password = "";
$password2 = "";
$u_check = "";

//reg form
$account = strip_tags(@$_POST['account']);
$gender = strip_tags(@$_POST['gender']);
$fullname = strip_tags(@$_POST['fullname']);
$email = strip_tags(@$_POST['email']);
$password = strip_tags(@$_POST['password']);
$password2 = strip_tags(@$_POST['password2']);


// will insert the data when the user presses the submit button.
// query will insert data into the database.
if ($submit){
    //check if user email already exists
    $u_check = mysqli_query ($connect,"SELECT email FROM users WHERE email ='$email' ");
    // count the amount of rows where e-mail = $email

    $check = mysqli_num_rows($u_check);
    if ($check == 0) {
        //all fields have been filled in
    if ($account&&$gender&&$name&&$email&&$password&&$password2){
        //if (!empty($account) && !empty($gender) && !empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($password) && !empty($password2)){
        //Password Match
    if ($password==$password2) {
        //Validation to check the max length of name is 25 characters 
    if (strlen($name)>25) {
    echo "You have exceed the max characters length for your name.";
    }
else 
{
    //check length of password - cant be more than 25 and less than 6 characters.
    if(strlen($password)>25 ||strlen($password)<6) {
        echo "You password has to be between 6 and 25 characters long";
    }
    else {  
    //encrypt password 
    $password = md5($password);
    $password2 = md5($password2);

    //insert registeration data on the DB
    $reg_query = mysqli_query ($connect, "INSERT INTO users VALUES ('','$fullname','$email','$gender','$password','$password2','','$account','no','')");
    die("<h3>Welcome to MyAstonSpace</h3>Login to your account to get started...");
        }
        }
        }
    else {
        echo "Your passwords do not match. Try Again!";
    }
    }
    else {
        echo "Please complete all the form to register.";
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "E-mail already registered. Try Again!";
    }
        }

?>



    <div class="container" style="position:absolute; top: 175px; left: 400px; ">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="area">

                        <div class="heading">
                            <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                        </div>
<br/>

                        <form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
                         <div class="controls"  style="font-size:16px">
                            <center>

                             <label class="radio-inline">
                             <input type="radio" name="account"> Student</label>
                             <label class="radio-inline">
                             <input type="radio" name="account"> Landlord
                             </label>
                            </center>
                        </div>
<br/>

                        <div class="controls" style="font-size:16px">
                    <center>

                        <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="gender"> Male</label>
                        <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="gender"> Female</label>
                        </form>
                    </center>
  </div>

<br/>

                <div class="form-group">
                <label for = "fullname"> Full Name: </label>
                <input type="text" name="fullname" class="form-control" required/> <br/>


                <label for = "email"> Email: </label>
                <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@aston.ac.uk" required/> <br/>


               <label for = "password"> Password: </label>
               <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" required/><br/><br/>

               <label for = "password2"> Retype Password: </label> 
               <input type="text" name="password2" class="form-control"  required/><br/><br/>
              </div>
             By clicking Sign Up, you agree on our <a href="#">terms and condition</a>. <br/><br/>  

             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sucess" name="submit" value="Sign Up" style="background-color:#337AB7; color:white;">

             </form>     
        </div>      
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container" style="position:absolute; top: 175px; left: 400px; ">
    <form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="area">
                    <div class="heading">
                        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls" style="font-size:16px">
                        <center>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="account" value="student"> Student</label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="account" value="landlord"> Landlord</label>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls" style="font-size:16px">
                        <center>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="male"> Male</label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female</label>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for = "fullname"> Full Name: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="fullname" class="form-control" required/> <br/>
                        <label for = "email"> Email: </label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@aston.ac.uk" required/> <br/>
                        <label for = "password"> Password: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" required/><br/><br/>
                        <label for = "password2"> Retype Password: </label> 
                        <input type="text" name="password2" class="form-control"  required/><br/><br/>
                    </div>
                    By clicking Sign Up, you agree on our <a href="#">terms and condition</a>. <br/><br/>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sucess" name="submit" value="Sign Up" style="background-color:#337AB7; color:white;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

correctly format your html tag by tag, when you have radio buttons, you need to add `value` attribute to it. Eg. `<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="account" value="student"> Student</label>` here i added `value="student"`

and accordingly your PHP submission goes something like this.

```
function controlUnwantedTags($getString) {
    //if anything else to be done, do here.
    return strip_tags($getString);
}

$errorMessages      = array();
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $account        = controlUnwantedTags($_POST["account"]);
    $gender         = controlUnwantedTags($_POST["gender"]);
    $fullname       = controlUnwantedTags($_POST["fullname"]);
    $email          = controlUnwantedTags($_POST["email"]);
    $password       = controlUnwantedTags($_POST["password"]);
    $password2      = controlUnwantedTags($_POST["password2"]);

    if($account=="") {
        $errorMessages[]    = "Missed Selecting Account Type";
    }
    if($gender=="") {
        $errorMessages[]    = "Missed Selecting Gender";
    }
    if($fullname=="") {
        $errorMessages[]    = "Missed Entering Name";
    }
    if($email=="") {
        $errorMessages[]    = "Missed Entering E-Mail";
    }
    else {
        //even check the correct email format
        //validate your email here, in case if it is unique everytime
    }
    if($password=="") {
        $errorMessages[]    = "Missed Entering Password";
    }
    else {
        //validate if you have some pattern match for password
    }
    if($password2=="") {
        $errorMessages[]    = "Missed Re-Entering Password";
    }
    if($password!="" and $password2!="" and $password!=$password2) {
        $errorMessages[]    = "Password Entered doesn't match, Please Re-enter.";
    }
    if(count($errorMessages)==0) {
        //database insertion goes here

        //redirect to your required page
    }
}

if(count($errorMessages)!=0) {
    echo "Could not proceed due to following reasons.<br />";
    echo implode("<br />", $errorMessages);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Edited Answer** (as OP says the submit button itself is not working)

what faulty thing i found, enclosing of form tag, which wasn't appropriate, so correct the html.

```
<div class="container" style="position:absolute; top: 175px; left: 400px; ">
    <form action="#" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="area">
                    <div class="heading">
                        <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls" style="font-size:16px">
                        <center>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="account"> Student</label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="account"> Landlord</label>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="controls" style="font-size:16px">
                        <center>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender"> Male</label>
                            <label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="gender"> Female</label>
                        </center>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for = "fullname"> Full Name: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="fullname" class="form-control" required/> <br/>
                        <label for = "email"> Email: </label>
                        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@aston.ac.uk" required/> <br/>
                        <label for = "password"> Password: </label>
                        <input type="text" name="password" class="form-control" required/><br/><br/>
                        <label for = "password2"> Retype Password: </label> 
                        <input type="text" name="password2" class="form-control"  required/><br/><br/>
                    </div>
                    By clicking Sign Up, you agree on our <a href="#">terms and condition</a>. <br/><br/>
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-sucess" name="submit" value="Sign Up" style="background-color:#337AB7; color:white;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

**Previous Answer** (as per OP it resulted with not entering into the below condition)

```
 if ($account&&$gender&&$name&&$email&&$password&&$password2){
```

the above condition is not allowing to proceed, as per my understanding, you are trying to validate the form elements here for not allowing null values.
so change the condition by simply adding a simple keywords `empty` which checks, whether the value is `NULL` or `NOT NULL`

```
if (!empty($account) && !empty($gender) && !empty($name) && !empty($email) && !empty($password) && !empty($password2)){
```

The above condition will check for not NULL values.

Comment: This piece of code is still not working. The submit button isnt doing anything when i click it. Can someone tell me where i have gone wrong. As i just changed some html/css code to bootstrap and didnt change any variables or php code.

Comment: hi @Aman.V, you mean there is no problem with php? the problem is with html/CSS!

Comment: you previously mentioned as, it takes you to output ('Please complete all the form to register.') everytime.

Comment: yes that did happen few times before however now when i press the submit button, nothing actually happens.

Comment: so im not completely sure what actually is the problem.

Comment: hey @Aman.V, check out your form tag enclosing, this isn't right. you are closing form tag twice, you need to enclose all the required elements within the form..

Comment: well catch mate. However, now when i press submit the same thing is being echoed "Please complete all the form to register." any solution to this?

Comment: you have missed values under radio buttons, while compiled in PHP, it will always return null, and will not allow to enter into if condition, so add the values under radio buttons..

Comment: Sorry could you give me an example of how i will place that and where?